# Python2.7 re fullmatch alternatives

Tags: regex, python-2.7, match

Is there a way to match a complete string before python3.4(as they introduced fullmatch() method here.)
For eg. If i have a string '*12.345*' and If i want to check for float with no exponential and i use the pattern: `r'-?(?:\d+())?(?:\.\d+())?'`. But this pattern also works for '*12.345abc*'.
How can i make re to not match second string '12.345abc'?
Thanks!

Comment: [Anchors](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) are your friend: `r'^-?(?:\d+())?(?:\.\d+())?$'`

Comment: thanks! works. and already answered as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use anchors in combination with `filter()` and `lambda()`:

```
import re

strings = ['12.345', '12.345abc']

rx = re.compile(r'^\d+(\.\d+)?$')

numbers = list(filter(lambda x: rx.match(x), strings))
print(numbers)
# ['12.345']
```

This makes sure no rubbish is matched afterwards.